# Is it possible to do Cobalt catalyzed directing group asisted meta C-H functionalization of arenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

Directing Group assisted Pd catalyzed (sp2)*meta*-C-H functionalization has a growing attention in recent years.
In addition, few examples can be found for *meta*-C-H functionalization via Rhodium. I am wondering whether it is possible to do *meta*-C-H functionalization using Cobalt as its a first-row transtion metal. Since Cobalt chemistry is somewhat different what sort challenges we are going to face? If someone could share any reported articles based on this chemistry, it is much appreciated.